# Does returning in contrast to not returning a value from a method have impact on performance?

Tags: java, optimization, methods, return

If i.e. there is an adding method for an object, and for constructing convenience,

`Objeckt o = new Objeckt().add(new Element());`

does it cost any more to use the method

```
Objeckt add(Element e){
    return this;
}
```

instead of

```
void add(Element e){

}
```

?

Comment: What kind of system are you designing that's so performance-critical?

Comment: I am just wondering if it makes any difference at all. Or if the value is none (void) it still needs to return a blank.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm voting to close this question as unclear. The answer of the this question depends on the jvm and the operating system used. Please review the technical documentation how bytecode is executed and sometimes optimized by just-in-time compiliation.

Comment: Basically [there are different bytecode instructions depending on the datatypes to return](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.8).  I see no reason why something like a _blank value_ has to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ventiseis:

[Object return](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.areturn)

(similarly for the primitive returns [ireturn](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.ireturn), [lreturn](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.lreturn), [freturn](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.freturn) and [dreturn](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.dreturn))

> If no exception is thrown, value is popped from the operand stack of the current frame (§2.6) and pushed onto the operand stack of the frame of the invoker. Any other values on the operand stack of the current method are discarded.

[void return](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.return)

> If no exception is thrown, any values on the operand stack of the current frame (§2.6) are discarded.

The specification states that:

*If a value is returned, the value is popped from the operand stack and pushed onto the operand stack of the invoking frame.*

*If no value is returned, nothing is to be popped or pushed.*

**Thus returning no value should be more efficient.**

Of course, this answer does not factor in optimization, in case the returned value is not used in the invoking frame.